# Draggable Modal Window Won't Allow to Click on Text Boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, draggable

I followed this:

http://embed.plnkr.co/NQihUs/

Added it into my js file and called `modal-movable` on my modal body div. It allows me to drag the modal but now it won't let me allow to click on the input/text boxes that I have on my modal.

Any ideas on how i can fix this?

I've managed to quickly fix this:

```
            dialogWrapper.on('mousedown', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Remove to allow text box click
                startX = event.pageX - x;
                startY = event.pageY - y;
                $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
            });
```